# React JS concate array and transform into new two dimension array and sort by the two dimension array data sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-native

I am working on a react native App
Say I have these array list:

```
let soldList1 = [
    {"itemCode":"X001" , "soldRate":0.0789},
    {"itemCode":"5555" , "soldRate":0.0543},
    {"itemCode":"3141" , "soldRate":0.0112},
    {"itemCode":"Mix-001" , "soldRate":0.01},
    {"itemCode":"7689-L" , "soldRate":0.005},
    {"itemCode":"1111" , "soldRate":0.003}
]

let soldList2 = [
    {"itemCode":"3141" , "soldRate":0.0712},    
    {"itemCode":"7689-L" , "soldRate":0.03},
    {"itemCode":"5555" , "soldRate":0.0234},    
    {"itemCode":"1111" , "soldRate":0.011},
    {"itemCode":"X001" , "soldRate":0.008},
    {"itemCode":"Mix-001" , "soldRate":0.004}
]

let soldList3 = [
    {"itemCode":"5555" , "soldRate":0.0339},   
    {"itemCode":"X001" , "soldRate":0.0221},
    {"itemCode":"3141" , "soldRate":0.0111},  
    {"itemCode":"1111" , "soldRate":0.0089},
    {"itemCode":"Mix-001" , "soldRate":0.0077},  
    {"itemCode":"7689-L" , "soldRate":0.0032}
]

let soldList4 =[
    {"itemCode":"8888" , "soldRate":0.13},   
    {"itemCode":"9999" , "soldRate":0.11},
    {"itemCode":"3141" , "soldRate":0.08},  
    {"itemCode":"1111" , "soldRate":0.07}
]


let soldList5 =[
    {"itemCode":"3141" , "soldRate":0.044},  
    {"itemCode":"1111" , "soldRate":0.011},
    {"itemCode":"8888" , "soldRate":0.0011},   
    {"itemCode":"9999" , "soldRate":0.0001}
]

let soldList6 =[
    {"itemCode":"Mix-001" , "soldRate":0.5678},  
    {"itemCode":"7689-L" , "soldRate":0.546}
    {"itemCode":"8888" , "soldRate":0.323},   
    {"itemCode":"9999" , "soldRate":0.0032},
    {"itemCode":"Mix-001" , "soldRate":0.0022},  
    {"itemCode":"UV-007" , "soldRate":0.0012}
    {"itemCode":"TT-08" , "soldRate":0.0011},  
    {"itemCode":"PP-03" , "soldRate":0.0009}
]
```

As you can see, some list got elements other list does not has, and each list item order is `desc order by 'soldRate'`,  and each list.length may be different as well.

So the goal is to concate these array list and processing to build a new array list, something like below:

```
let finalAllConcateAndSortedByDataSumList = [
    {"itemCode":"Mix-001" , "data": [0.01, 0.004, 0.0077, 0, 0, 0.5678], "dataSum":0.5895},    
    {"itemCode":"7689-L" , "data": [0.005, 0.03, 0.0032, 0, 0, 0.546], "dataSum":0.5842},       
    {"itemCode":"8888" , "data": [0, 0, 0, 0.13, 0.0011, 0.323], "dataSum":0.4541},            
    {"itemCode":"3141" , "data": [0.0112, 0.0712, 0.0111, 0.08, 0.044, 0], "dataSum":0.2175},   
    {"itemCode":"X001" , "data": [0.0789, 0.008, 0.0221, 0, 0, 0.0221], "dataSum":0.1311},   
    {"itemCode":"9999" , "data": [0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0.0001, 0.0032], "dataSum":0.1133},           
    {"itemCode":"5555" , "data": [0.0543, 0.0234, 0.0339, 0, 0, 0], "dataSum":0.1116},         
    {"itemCode":"1111" , "data": [0.003, 0.011, 0.0089, 0.07, 0.011, 0], "dataSum":0.1039},     
    {"itemCode":"UV-007" , "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0012], "dataSum":0.0012},            
    {"itemCode":"TT-08" , "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0011], "dataSum":0.0011},                 
    {"itemCode":"PP-03" , "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0009], "dataSum":0.0009},             
]
```

So as you can see, all the `'soldRate'` elements from list 1 2 3 4 5 6 above has been concate and generated into new array list `'data'` property,  the position of each data order is strickly the same as above original list 1 2 3 4 5 6.... if the element value in position is not existing in any of the original list,  it is then a '0' value

And eventually the each object in finalAllConcateAndSortedByDataSumList, the data array will be sum up into property `'dataSum'`

Then the new list finalAllConcateAndSortedByDataSumList  is `desc order by dataSum`

This is my personal attempt to make it work, but it does not work...

```
let finalAllConcateAndSortedByDataSumList = soldList1.concat(soldList2)
.concat(soldList3)
.concat(soldList4)
.concat(soldList5)
.concat(soldList16).map((item) => {
    let newItem = { itemCode: item.itemCode, data: [item.soldRate], dataSum: Math.sum([item.soldRate])}
    return newItem
}).sort((item) => { return item.dataSum})
```

So seeking for help here,  code example would be really helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first extract all the unique `itemCode` values there are in the arrays, and then loop over them and add either the `soldRate` or `0` to the result if the `itemCode` is present in each array.

```js
let soldList1 = [
  { itemCode: "X001", soldRate: 0.0789 },
  { itemCode: "5555", soldRate: 0.0543 },
  { itemCode: "3141", soldRate: 0.0112 },
  { itemCode: "Mix-001", soldRate: 0.01 },
  { itemCode: "7689-L", soldRate: 0.005 },
  { itemCode: "1111", soldRate: 0.003 }
];

let soldList2 = [
  { itemCode: "3141", soldRate: 0.0712 },
  { itemCode: "7689-L", soldRate: 0.03 },
  { itemCode: "5555", soldRate: 0.0234 },
  { itemCode: "1111", soldRate: 0.011 },
  { itemCode: "X001", soldRate: 0.008 },
  { itemCode: "Mix-001", soldRate: 0.004 }
];

let soldList3 = [
  { itemCode: "5555", soldRate: 0.0339 },
  { itemCode: "X001", soldRate: 0.0221 },
  { itemCode: "3141", soldRate: 0.0111 },
  { itemCode: "1111", soldRate: 0.0089 },
  { itemCode: "Mix-001", soldRate: 0.0077 },
  { itemCode: "7689-L", soldRate: 0.0032 }
];

let soldList4 = [
  { itemCode: "8888", soldRate: 0.13 },
  { itemCode: "9999", soldRate: 0.11 },
  { itemCode: "3141", soldRate: 0.08 },
  { itemCode: "1111", soldRate: 0.07 }
];

let soldList5 = [
  { itemCode: "3141", soldRate: 0.044 },
  { itemCode: "1111", soldRate: 0.011 },
  { itemCode: "8888", soldRate: 0.0011 },
  { itemCode: "9999", soldRate: 0.0001 }
];

let soldList6 = [
  { itemCode: "Mix-001", soldRate: 0.5678 },
  { itemCode: "7689-L", soldRate: 0.546 },
  { itemCode: "8888", soldRate: 0.323 },
  { itemCode: "9999", soldRate: 0.0032 },
  { itemCode: "Mix-001", soldRate: 0.0022 },
  { itemCode: "UV-007", soldRate: 0.0012 },
  { itemCode: "TT-08", soldRate: 0.0011 },
  { itemCode: "PP-03", soldRate: 0.0009 }
];

function sumSoldRates(...arrs) {
  let itemCodes = [].concat(...arrs).reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if (!acc.includes(obj.itemCode)) {
      acc.push(obj.itemCode);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  let result = itemCodes.map(code => {
    let obj = { itemCode: code, data: [], dataSum: 0 };

    arrs.forEach(arr => {
      let item = arr.find(el => el.itemCode === code);

      if (item) {
        obj.data.push(item.soldRate);
        obj.dataSum += item.soldRate;
      } else {
        obj.data.push(0);
      }
    });

    return obj;
  });

  result.sort((a, b) => b.dataSum - a.dataSum);

  return result;
}

let result = sumSoldRates(
  soldList1,
  soldList2,
  soldList3,
  soldList4,
  soldList5,
  soldList6
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I broke your process down into various steps, as it makes it clearer what you are doing (and easier to debug). The code may not be as compact or "elegant" as other answers, but I believe it is easier to understand this way.

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/613nxjqz1k) that shows this in action (see the console output).

```
const getItemCodes = (list) => {
  return list.map(item => item.itemCode)
}

const getDataValue = (list, itemCode) => {
  let index = list.findIndex(item => item.itemCode === itemCode)
  return (index === -1 ? 0 : list[index].soldRate)
}

const sumArray = (array) => {
  const sum = array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return (parseFloat(prev) + parseFloat(curr))
  })
  return sum.toFixed(4)
}

const sortByDataSum = (array) => {
  array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.dataSum > b.dataSum) {
      return -1
    } else if (a.dataSum < b.dataSum) {
      return 1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })
  return array
}

// concat all item codes together, which will result in duplicates
let allItemCodes = [...getItemCodes(soldList1),
                    ...getItemCodes(soldList2),
                    ...getItemCodes(soldList3),
                    ...getItemCodes(soldList4),
                    ...getItemCodes(soldList5),
                    ...getItemCodes(soldList6)]

// remove duplicate codes
allItemCodes = [...new Set(allItemCodes)] 

let finalList = []

allItemCodes.forEach((code) => {
  let item = {
    'itemCode': code,
    'data': [getDataValue(soldList1, code),
             getDataValue(soldList2, code),
             getDataValue(soldList3, code),
             getDataValue(soldList4, code),
             getDataValue(soldList5, code),
             getDataValue(soldList6, code)]
  }
  item.dataSum = sumArray(item.data)
  finalList.push(item)
})

sortByDataSum(finalList)
console.log(finalList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of arrays in dicts:

```
let result = {} 
soldList1.concat(soldList2)
.concat(soldList3)
.concat(soldList4)
.concat(soldList5)
.concat(soldList6)
.forEach(item => {
  if(result[item.itemCode]) {
    result[item.itemCode].data.push(item.soldRate);
    result[item.itemCode].dataSum += item.soldRate;
  } else {
    result[item.itemCode] = {data: [item.soldRate], itemCode: item.itemCode, dataSum: item.soldRate};
  }
});
let finalAllConcateAndSortedByDataSumList = Object.values(result).sort((item) => { return item.dataSum})

console.log(finalAllConcateAndSortedByDataSumList);
```